# disable select value after selecting a value from one select tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have two select option for time selecting if i would select one value say 9:00am from one select tag 9:00am should be disabled from other select tag code is

```
<select>
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option> </select> so on.



<select>
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option> </select> so on..
```

These are the two select tag ..

Thanks in Advance,

Ameeth

Comment: And your approach to solve this problem looks like …?

Comment: check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dZqEu/2/)

Comment: Thanks plain jane this is the one i am looking for ..

Comment: hi plain jane i just copied the code from jsfiddle into local but it is not working what could be the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this may be what you're looking for

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xegKj

html:

```
<select id="TimeFirst" onChange="fSetTimeOptions(this,'TimeSecond');">
  <option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
  <option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
</select>
<select id="TimeSecond" onChange="fSetTimeOptions(this,'TimeFirst');">
  <option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
  <option value="10:00am">10:00am</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
function fSetTimeOptions(selObj, fvOtherSel) {
  var OtherSel = document.getElementById(fvOtherSel);
  var TimeValue = selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value;
  alert(TimeValue);
  for (var i = 0; i < OtherSel.options.length; i++) {
         if (OtherSel.options[i].value == TimeValue) {
             OtherSel.options[i].disabled = true;
         } else {
             OtherSel.options[i].disabled = false; 
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked i have another question like can we disable values top values from the selected including selected  and only bottom values have to made selected

Answer (score 1):

HTML Code :

```
<select id="sel1" onchange="disableSelect(this);">
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option> </select>

<select id="sel2">
<option value="9:00am">9:00am</option>
<option value="10:00am">10:00am</option> </select>
```

Javascript :

```
function disableSelect(content) {
  var val = content.value;
  var mySel = document.getElementById("sel2");

  for (var i = 0; i < mySel.options.length; i++) { 

    if (mySel.options[i].value == val) {
      mySel.options[i].disabled=true;
    }
    else {
      mySel.options[i].disabled=false;
    }
  } 
}
```

You have to find the option in the other select using the value of the current select :

```
if (mySel.options[i].value == val) {
    mySel.options[i].disabled=true;
}
```

Then if it is true, disable it. or else, you have to enable it.
If you do not enable it back, then if user changes the value again in "sel1", the value that is previously disabled in "sel2" can not be enabled again.

Comment: it worked i have another question like can we disable values top values from the selected including selected and only bottom values have to made selected

Comment: Check the new answer i have added

Comment: thanks prabakaran it is working

Answer (score 1):

Add two inner for loops inside the if condition to disable the previous values and delete the else part.

I have added this

```
   for(var j=i;j>=0;j--) {
        mySel.options[j].disabled=true;
     }
     for(j=i+1;j<mySel.options.length; j++) {
        mySel.options[j].disabled=false;
     }
```

inside the if condition.

the code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < mySel.options.length; i++) { 

  if (mySel.options[i].value == val) {
    mySel.options[i].disabled=true;

     for(var j=i;j>=0;j--) {
        mySel.options[j].disabled=true;
     }
     for(j=i+1;j<mySel.options.length; j++) {
        mySel.options[j].disabled=false;
     }

  }    
}
```